# AndEngine removing line after removing finger

Tags: android, andengine

I'm trying to detach a line after I remove my finger so on ACTION_UP ..
it doesn't seem to work

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
            mScene = new Scene();

            mScene.setOnSceneTouchListener(new IOnSceneTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(final Scene pScene, final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
                   if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                      isDrawing = true;
                      i = 0;
                   }
                   if (isDrawing = true) {
                      rec[i] = new Rectangle(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(), pSceneTouchEvent.getY(), 1, 1, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                      if (i != 0) {
                         l = new Line(rec[i-1].getX(), rec[i-1].getY(), rec[i].getX(), rec[i].getY(), getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                         l.setColor(0.5f, 1f, 0.3f);
                         mScene.attachChild(l);
                      }
                      i++;
                   }
                   if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                       isDrawing = false;
                       mScene.detachChild(l);
                    }
                   return true;
                }
             });

            pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(mScene);
    }
```

in ACTION_DOWN it'll draw the line using my finger, but in ACTION_UP the line should detach, why it's not ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

```
if(isDrawing = true)
```

You are assigning isDrawing to 'true' instead of comparing its value to 'true'.
THEN, the if statement is checked, which will be true EVERY time.  This will cause you to draw EVERY time.
Change it to:

```
if(isDrawing)
```